# How can i run my service on a clustered environment?

Tags: java, apache, distributed, clustering

How can i run my service on a clustered environment ?

Any products out there to help me out. This product should take care of

managing the cluster, cluster failover, rebalancing in case of node failure running the service on any of the partitioned node. I was evaluating Apache Helix but could not find out much material and sample projects on this.

My project is a spring MVC , tomcat java project running on single server and we are planning to expand it to multiple servers.